# Memory leaks in OfflineAudioContext

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Memory leaks in `OfflineAudioContext`.

Launch *Task Manager* in chrome. After 10 times run `createBuffer` memory used 1.5GB. After the tab exceeds the RAM limit, it will break.

**How can I avoid memory leaks?**

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5d2twrqp/).

```js
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// define variables

var play = document.querySelector('.play');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var buffer = document.querySelector('.buffer');
var myBuffer = null;

var rendering = false;
// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source

function getData() {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/storage.cowrite.decodeapps.io/Materials/Media/Audio/5a0aca5f35965-20171114-105007.mp3', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
    progress.innerText = 'loaded';
    var audioData = request.response;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
      myBuffer = buffer;

      createBuffer();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
      // Note: The promise should reject when startRendering is called a second time on an OfflineAudioContext
    });
  }
  request.send();
}
buffer.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
progress.innerText = 'loading...';
var cntRenfered = 0;

function createBuffer() {
  var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2, myBuffer.length, myBuffer.sampleRate);
  var source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = myBuffer;
  source.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
  source.start();
  //source.loop = true;
  offlineCtx.oncomplete = function(e) {
    progress.innerText = 'completed';
    buffer.removeAttribute('disabled');
    source.disconnect(offlineCtx.destination);
    cntRenfered++;
    buffer.innerText = 'reCreateBuffer ' + cntRenfered;
  }
  offlineCtx.startRendering();
}

buffer.onclick = function() {
  progress.innerText = 'rendering...';
  buffer.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  createBuffer();
}

getData();
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  loading
</div>


<button class="buffer">
  reCreateBuffer
</button>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your goal is here.

You haven't asked a question. As far as I can tell, you've basically submitted a bug report – except StackOverflow doesn't make Chrome.

Comment: Does this come to the point it crashes because there is no more memory available? Otherwise, it's perfectly fine. The browser uses what is available. You might want to facilitate GC work by calling `offlineCtx.close()` once it's done its job, but nothing to worry about, (*uncompressed 2 channels raw PCM data of an 14MB mp3) x10* might be around this size.

Comment: @Kaiido `OfflineAudioContext` don't have method `close`.

Comment: @KevinEnnis My question is obvious. After the tab exceeds the RAM limit, it will break.

Comment: @Kaiido Just run 30 times the function `createBuffer` and the tab will break.

Comment: You are right about `close`, my bad. However, I can't reproduce the tab crash. With 16G RAM, when used memory arrives around 8G (clicked 80 times), the GC kicks in and it falls down to 300MB.

Comment: @Kaiido On my windows 10 with 16GB ram after 30 times chrome crash. Tab used memory more 4GB. If you leave the tab with 2GB memory open, will the GC work? The use of memory will decrease after 10 minutes, for example?

Comment: It doesn't... Still not sure if you'll get any solution from SO. Open an issue on chromium, your tab should not crash.

Comment: @Kaiido this is not only chrome bug. In firefox the same!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Really not trying to cause trouble, but your question is definitely not obvious to me (because you never asked one). Do you want to know why this happens? How to prevent it? Something else? Unclear.

Comment: @KevinEnnis i update question. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm find workaround.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ymngy7u1/).

```js
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// define variables

var play = document.querySelector('.play');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var buffer = document.querySelector('.buffer');
var myBuffer = null;

var rendering = false;
// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source

function getData() {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/storage.cowrite.decodeapps.io/Materials/Media/Audio/5a0aca5f35965-20171114-105007.mp3', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
    progress.innerText = 'loaded';
    var audioData = request.response;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(b) {
      myBuffer = b;
      buffer.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
      // Note: The promise should reject when startRendering is called a second time on an OfflineAudioContext
    });
  }
  request.send();
}
buffer.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
progress.innerText = 'loading...';
var cntRenfered = 0;

function createBuffer() {
  var offlineCtx = getIFrameOfflineContext(2, myBuffer.length, myBuffer.sampleRate);
  var source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = myBuffer;
  source.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
  source.start();
  //source.loop = true;
  offlineCtx.oncomplete = function(e) {
    console.log('Rendering completed successfully');
    progress.innerText = 'completed';
    buffer.removeAttribute('disabled');
    source.disconnect(offlineCtx.destination);
    cntRenfered++;
    buffer.innerText = 'reCreateBuffer ' + cntRenfered;
    setTimeout(function() {
      IFrameReload();
    });
  }
  offlineCtx.startRendering();
}

buffer.onclick = function() {
  progress.innerText = 'rendering...';
  buffer.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  createBuffer();
}

getData();
var iFrame;

function createIframe() {
  iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
  iFrame.style.display = 'none';
  iFrame.onload = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML =
      `
        function reload() {
          location.reload();
        }

        function createOfflineContext(NUMBER_OF_CHANNEL, duration, sampleRate) {
          return new (window.OfflineAudioContext || window.webkitOfflineAudioContext)(NUMBER_OF_CHANNEL,duration,sampleRate);
        }
      `;
    iFrame.contentDocument.body.appendChild(script);
  };
  document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
}

function getIFrameOfflineContext(NUMBER_OF_CHANNEL, duration, sampleRate) {
  return iFrame.contentWindow.createOfflineContext(NUMBER_OF_CHANNEL, duration, sampleRate);
}

function IFrameReload() {
  iFrame.contentWindow.reload();
}


createIframe();
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  loading
</div>

<button class="buffer">
  reCreateBuffer
</button>
```